# finish() vs startActivity()

Tags: android, bundle, state, onsaveinstancestate

According to Android documentation, finish() does exactly what the "back" button does. So basically onStop() is called when I call finish().

I tried to override onStateSaveInstance() to save the current state, but it is never called. However, if I go to the previous activity by creating a new Intent and using startActivity(), the method onStateSaveInstance() is called. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: `finish() does exactly what the "back" button does.` except when your `super.onBackPressed()` doesn't close the activity yet but rather delegates it to the fragment backstack, etc

Comment: `I tried to override onStateSaveInstance() to save the current state, but it is never called.` that is for configuration changes and process death, not for when your Activity is actually finishing.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically onStop() is called when I call finish().

Not necessarily. `onStop()` is called when your activity is no longer visible. `finish()` only triggers a call to `onStop()` if the activity is visible when you call `finish()`.

> I tried to override onStateSaveInstance() to save the current state, but it is never called

Correct. You are destroying the activity. There is no instance state to be saved.

> However, if I go to the previous activity by creating a new Intent and using startActivity(), the method onStateSaveInstance() is called

Not necessarily. It will depend on `Intent` flags, `android:launchMode` in the manifest, etc.

> Is there a reason for that?

`onSaveInstanceState()` will not be called when your activity is being destroyed. There is no instance state to be saved, as the instance is going away.

Comment: I know that there is no guarantee that the activity is destroyed, the operating system handles this. Is this an exception?

Comment: @Florin: Is *what* an exception to *what*?

Comment: You said that onSaveInstanceState() is not called because the activity is being destroyed. But I know that the operating system handles things like this and there is no guarantee that an activity does not exist anymore.

Comment: @Florin: If you call `finish()`, the activity is being destroyed. I cannot think of a scenario in which calling `finish()` does not destroy the activity.